# Qt Creator + gdcm (Grassroots DICOM): can't link libraries

Tags: qt, gdcm

I'm using Qt Creator 2.4.1 under Xubuntu 11.10.

I've installed libgdcm2-dev (2.0.17) in repositories.

Now I have

> /usr/include/gdcm-2.0
>   /usr/lib/gdcm-2.0*

and a lot of *.so related to gdcm in */usr/lib/*

Writing code, I can autocomplete sentences with gdcm classes and functions (the IDE finds them), but compiling, it gives me error messages like:

My code:

```
#include <gdcmImageReader.h>
...
gdcm::ImageReader ir;
```

I get:

> error: undefined reference to `gdcm::ImageReader::ImageReader()'

I've tried with:

```
#include "/usr/include/gdcm-2.0/ImageImageReader.h"
```

With this one, it works from a simple editor like Geany.

In my .pro file I have

```
INCLUDEPATH    += /usr/include/gdcm-2.0
LIBS           += -L/usr/lib/
```

What could I try? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .pro file you should write something like :

```
LIBS += -lgdcm-2.0
```

the main part is `LIBS += -l` then depends on library you are using..

Comment: It wasn't exactly that, but that's the idea. I put the exact solution. Thank you!